# How to get access to the docker cmd from docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I've tried to get access to `docker` command from a container I got an issue says that

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. Is the docker daemon running?

the container created using this CMD line :

```sh
sudo docker run  -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket --name jenkins-master -d jenkins
```

Comment: your user is not added to `docker` group. After you add it, don't forget to `exit` and log back in so that your `shell` is reinitialized. To attach to the process use `docker exec -it <container> sh`, to attach to the running process use `docker attach`. The CLI you're using (`docker run`) starts a new container, and not "get access" !!!

Comment: I mean by " get access" not to get into container using shell I wantt to run docker command from the container,
@azbarcea thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Hey Guys the issue was in the socket volume I mean in this section

-v /var/run/docker.sock:/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket

should be change to

-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

Comment: depends how your socket is configured. run `systemctl status docker` and you get the file where docker is configured (different OS, will be different file), and then in that `.service` file you will get where your socker is configured.

Comment: You're right it depends on the installed OS, I used just the locate cmd to look for docker.sock, because in the .service file was just a containerd.sock  so I used the locate cmd I got the path , I mount it , and everything went well , 
Thanks for your support @azbarcea